# sending an email using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to come up a way to send email via `JavaScript`, and after some search I found this[tutorial](https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782) exampling how to do it using `Mandrill`.
Thus, I went ahead trying the API, and I'm not having success so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateMyForm()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
        data: {
              ‘key’: ‘MY KEY’,
              ‘message’: {
                ‘from_email’: ‘SOMEONE@EMAIL.COM’,
                ‘to’: [
                    {
                        ‘email’: ‘MY@EMAIL.COM’,
                        ‘name’: ‘MYSELF’,
                        ‘type’: ‘to’
                    }
                 ],
               ‘autotext’: ‘true’,
               ‘subject’: ‘Hello World’,
               ‘html’: ‘YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!’
            }
        }
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
    Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
    Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
    Message:<br />
    <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
    <input id="sendmail" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Moreover, I see `firebug` reporting me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id


â€˜keyâ€™: â€˜MY_KEY€™,
```

When I look at the page, I see:

```
function validateMyForm()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
        data: {
              â€˜keyâ€™: â€˜MY_KEY€™,
              â€˜messageâ€™: {
                â€˜from_emailâ€™: â€˜MY_EMAIL@EMAIL.COM€™,
                â€˜toâ€™: [
                    {
                        â€˜emailâ€™: â€˜SOMEONE'S EMAILâ€™,
                        â€˜nameâ€™: â€˜MY NAMEâ€™,
                        â€˜typeâ€™: â€˜toâ€™
                    }
                 ],
               â€˜autotextâ€™: â€˜trueâ€™,
               â€˜subjectâ€™: â€˜Hello Worldâ€™,
               â€˜htmlâ€™: â€˜YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!â€™
            }
        }
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
        });
}
```

I have no idea why `Firefox` is doing that ... So there are two problems I'm asking in this question:

- Why is Firefox returning those weird symbols?
- How can I make the `validateMyForm()` function to send me an email?

Comment: I would think about encoding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is Firefox returning those weird symbols?

Ensure that you are using the right encoding to read the file - It is look like you saved the file with an encoding that FireFox can't infer.

> How can I make the validateMyForm() function to send me an email?

You're using funky quotes: ‘. Replace them with single quotes: ', example:

```
data: {
      'key': 'MY KEY',
      'message': {
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using funky quotes: `‘`. Change them to single quotes: `'`.